# How do I deploy an ASP.NET MVC web site using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express Edition?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm having problems deploying my website to the live server using VWD 2010 Express. I had done this without a problem in VWD 2008 Express. But, it seems that the tools for publishing a site are very different from 2008 to 2010.

What I've tried so far is to go to

- Project>Package/Publish Settings and I change configuration to release
- uncheck "Create deployment as a zip file"
- I specify the location where the package will be created
- and then I go to Project>Build Deployment Package

VWD 2010 express shows:

> ------ Build started: Project: genesis, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>
> genesis -> C:\Documents and Settings\computeruser\pathtoproject\projectname\projectname\bin\projectname.dll
>
> ------ Publish started: Project: genesis, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>
> ========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
>
> ========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

The problem is when I go to the publish location, the website gets buried in a bunch of folders. I have to drill 5-10 folders deep to reach the actual web site files.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I get VWD 2010 Express to simply build the site in the location I specify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tackled this very problem today. Since we have Final Builder handling our builds, I just created a FileSet in that with a bunch of exclusions, and then a later step in my build script copies those files to my deployment target folder.

You could reproduce the same result by just using xcopy excluding the file types you don't need on your web server.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What is xcopy? The more I look into VWD2010 the more upset I'm getting with Microsoft. In VWD2008 I could click WebSite>Publish> tell it where I wanted it to go and... boom... it worked. Now I have to go to 3rd party apps to publish a website on IIS?

Comment: xcopy is the old DOS command for copying multiple files / folders. You could also look at robocopy which is a server copying utility.

Both are included in the operating system. Just open up a command prompt and type `xcopy` or `robocopy` and you should get a description of how to use it.

Comment: Thanks... I can see how a program like that would be nice. I tried just copying and pasting the files from my computer straight into server, that worked too. I didn't know that just building the project in vwd would be able to run if you just copy it to the server. I thought VWD did some magical thing to get the site ready for a server.